# How could I make sibling inline-level elements be in separate line boxes?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div>
  <em style="background-color: aqua;">
      Line box 1
  </em>
  <span id="span2" style="background-color: aquamarine;">
      another sibling (line box 2)
  </span>
</div>
```

1. Will the sibling `inline-level` elements **always** be placed next to each other?

I was expecting `#span2` to be in *another line box*.

2. How could I make 2 *sibling* inline-level elements be in separate *line boxes*?

If you can give me the specification of this behavior it would be great.

Comment: "I was expecting #span2 to be in another line box." Why?

Comment: For the rules, see the [CSS Inline Layout Module Level 3 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/), and, especially for question 2, the [CSS Text Module Level 3 Specification, section 5. Line Breaking and Word Boundaries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#line-breaking)

Comment: hi @Alohci, another question, where does it say that a *inline box* is on the **same line box** as its parent inline box? For example, `<span>line box 1<span>span in the same line box</span></span>`

Comment: Well, it doesn't, because it's not true. All we can say it that for pure inline boxes, the fragments of an inline box will be distributed across a subset of the line boxes that the fragments of its parent inline box are distributed across.

Comment: Excellent @Alohci, now I understand better, by "pure" inline boxes do you mean elements with `display: inline`?

Comment: @gus. Yes. As opposed to **inline-level** boxes, where situation is far more complicated

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand quite well what you want. Try this :

CSS

```
.my-class > * {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="my-class">
  <em style="background-color: aqua;">
      Line box 1
  </em>
  <span id="span2" style="background-color: aquamarine;">
      another sibling (line box 2)
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Frank Perrin, yeah, but, I want to understand the behavior, not a solution as such.

Comment: inline elements like 'em' or 'span' have "display: inline;" default style which lead them to be displayed "inline".
So I give them the "display: block;" style. The way I do it, is to select all the direct children ( '> *' css selector ) of the element having "my-class" class (here the 'div').
Hoping this is clear..